# Sharing data between Mongoose middleware methods pre save and post save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

### SEE UPDATED EXAMPLE CODE @ BOTTOM

I'm using Mongoose (which is awesome btw!) in my current NodeJS projects, and I have a MDB collection thats going to store the changes of documents in a different collection (Basically a *changelog* storing what was modified)

How I'm trying to accomplish that is create a function that stores a JSON version of the document, which is done via the `pre('save')` hook. Then create another hook, which gets executed via `post('save')`, to compare the data stored in `pre('save')`, and compare it with the documents new data.

Heres what I have thus far:

```js
var origDocument 
var testVar = 'Goodbye World'

module.exports = ( schema, options ) => {
    schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {
        // Store the original value of the documents attrCache.Description value
        origDocument = this.toJSON().attrCache.Description

        // Change the testVar value to see if the change is reflected in post(save)
        testVar = 'Hello World'
        next()
    } )

    schema.post( 'save', function(  ) {
        // Attempt to compare the documents previous value of attrCache.Description, with the new value
        console.log("BEFORE:", origDocument)
        console.log("AFTER:", this.toJSON().attrCache.Description)

        // Both of the above values are the same! >.<

        console.log('post(save):',testVar) // result: post(save):Hello World
        // But the above works just fine..
    } )
}
```

I originally didn't think this would work. To test that the two hooks get executed in the same scope, I created a test variable at the top of the page called `testVar` with some arbitrary value, then in the `post(save)` hook, retrieved the `testVar`, and the value modification of that variable **was seen** in the post save hook.

So from there, I just stored the value of `this.toJSON()` in a variable, then in the post(save) hook, I am trying to retrieve the cached version of this document, and compare it to `this.toJSON()`. However, it doesn't look like the document from the `pre(save)` doesnt hold the pre-modified data, it somehow has the value of the document **after** it was updated.

So why can I update the value of `testVar` from within a `pre(save)` hook, and that change is reflected from a `post(save)` hook function, but I cant do the same thing with the document itself?

Is what im trying to do here even possible? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not - How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

### Update

Per the advice from @Avraam, I tried to run the data through `JSON.stringify()` before saving it in memory via the `pre(save)` hook, then do the same in the `post(save)`, like so:

```js
var origDocument 

module.exports = ( schema, options ) => {
    schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {

        origDocument = JSON.stringify( this.toJSON().attributes[1].value )

        // Should store and output the CURRENT value as it was before the 
        // document update... but it displays the NEW value somehow
        console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE] ORIGINAL value:', origDocument )

        next()
    } )

    schema.post( 'save', function(  ) {
        var newDocument = JSON.stringify(this.toJSON().attributes[1].value)

        console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE] UPDATED value:', newDocument )
    } )
}
```

And here's the script that updates the mongoose document:

```js
Asset.getAsset( '56d0819b655baf4a4a7f9cad' )
    .then( assetDoc => {
        // Display original value of attribute
        console.log('[QUERY] ORIGINAL value:', assetDoc.attributes[1].value)

        var updateNum = parseInt( assetDoc.__v )+1
        assetDoc.attr('Description').set('Revision: ' + updateNum )

        return assetDoc.save()
    } )
    .then(data => {
        // Display the new value of the attribute
        console.log('[QUERY] UPDATED value:', data.attributes[1].value)
        //console.log('DONE')
    })
    .catch( err => console.error( 'ERROR:',err ) )
```

Heres the console output when I run the New script:

```
[QUERY] ORIGINAL value: Revision: 67
[MIDDLEWARE] ORIGINAL value: "Revision: 68"
[MIDDLEWARE] UPDATED value: "Revision: 68"
[QUERY] UPDATED value: Revision: 68
```

As you can see, the *[QUERY] ORIGINAL* value and the *[QUERY] UPDATED* values show that there was an update. But the *[MIDDLEWARE]* original/updated values are still the same... So im still stuck as to why

### UPDATE

I figured maybe I could provide a more simplified but detailed example.

Heres the middleware module thats supposed to compare the `pre(save)` and

`post(save)`:
    'use strict'

```
import _ from 'moar-lodash'
import * as appRoot from 'app-root-path'
import Mongoose from 'mongoose'
import diff from 'deep-diff'

var originalDesc 


module.exports = ( schema, options ) => {
    schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {
        originalDesc =  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.toJSON() ) ).attributes[1].value

        console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE ORIGINAL Desc]\n\t', originalDesc )
        next()
    } )

    schema.post( 'save', function(  ) {
        var newDesc =  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.toJSON() ) ).attributes[1].value

        console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE NEW Desc]\n\t', newDesc)
    } )
}
```

Then heres the the code that uses the `Asset` model and updates the `Description` attribute...

```js
'use strict'

import _ from 'moar-lodash'
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import Mongoose from 'mongoose'
import Async from 'async'
import Util from 'util'
import * as appRoot from 'app-root-path'

Mongoose.Promise = Promise

Mongoose.connect( appRoot.require('./dist/lib/config').database.connection )

const accountLib = appRoot.require('./dist/lib/account')

const models = require( '../models' )( Mongoose )

models.Asset.getAsset( '56d0819b655baf4a4a7f9cad' )
    .then( assetDoc => {
        var jqDoc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(assetDoc.toJSON()))

        // Show the CURRENT description
        console.log('[IN QUERY - Before Modify]\n\t', jqDoc.attributes[1].value)

        assetDoc.attr('Description').set( 'Date-'+Date.now() )

        return assetDoc.save()

    } )
    .then(data => {
        // Just show the Description AFTER it was saved
        console.log('[AFTER QUERY - AFTER Modify]\n\t', data.attributes[1].value)
    })
    .catch( err => console.error( 'ERROR:',err ) )
    .finally( () => {
        Mongoose.connection.close()
        console.log('# Connection Closed')
    })


[IN QUERY - Before Modify]
     Date-1474915946697
[MIDDLEWARE ORIGINAL Desc]
     Date-1474916372134
[MIDDLEWARE NEW Desc]
     Date-1474916372134
[AFTER QUERY - AFTER Modify]
     Date-1474916372134
# Connection Closed
```

Comment: I seriously cant get why it in the first console output (first line of last snippet), but un the function of the post middleware hook, it doesnt

Comment: what do `console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE ORIGINAL Desc]\n\t', this. attributes )` and `console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE NEW Desc]\n\t', this.attributes)` show?

Comment: @Justin Do you actually want both versions of the data, or do you want to know if a certain property has been changed?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, The first part of your question is correctly answered by Avraam Mavridis 
so I will only focus on your last update in the question.

`pre.save` actually **doesn't** hold the actual document that currently exixts in the database, instead it is the document which is going to be saved, and contains the changes done to the document, i.e. the updated document.

`post.save` holds the real document that is stored in the database, hence still  the updated version. So you can not see the change that is done just looking at `this` in both `pre` and `post` `save`.

Now if you want to see the real values that existed in the database you need to fetch it from database before it is changed and saved, i.e. in `pre.save`.

---

One way you could do this is simply query the document from database

```
var originalDesc 


module.exports = ( schema, options ) => {
    schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {
        Asset.getAsset( '56d0819b655baf4a4a7f9cad' )
        .then( assetDoc => {
             originalDesc = assetDoc.attributes[1].value;
             console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE ORIGINAL Desc]\n\t', originalDesc )
             next()
         } );
    } );

    schema.post( 'save', function(  ) {
        var newDesc = this.toJSON().attributes[1].value
        console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE NEW Desc]\n\t', newDesc)
    } )
}
```

---

There is an alternative way than this using custom setter, and there is already a good [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546870/3556874), but this would require to set a custom setter for each property

```
schema.path('name').set(function (newVal) {
   this.originalDesc = this.Description;
});
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE ORIGINAL Desc]\n\t', this.originalDesc )
  next();
})
schema.post( 'save', function(  ) {
  var newDesc = this.toJSON().attributes[1].value
  console.log( '[MIDDLEWARE NEW Desc]\n\t', newDesc)
} )
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `origDocument` has reference to the `this.toJSON()` and the moment you call the `console.log` the value of the actual object where the reference points has already change. Use something like `JSON.stringify` to compare the values.

`origDocument = JSON.stringify( this.toJSON() )`

Comment: I tried that, it didnt seem to work.. Ill update teh main post with details

Comment: if you want to post up a full example of it working, then ill be more than happy to accept it and give you the bounty. You do see that in the `pre(save)`, im saving it as `origDocument = JSON.stringify( this.toJSON().attributes[1].value )`, right? Thats exactly what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how the pre/post hooks work in mongoose. When you grab the document (As you are doing) and resaving it. It will not have whatever variable was originally in the document. It will have whatever is currently in the document.

So, you are doing this:

1. Grab Document (67)
2. Modify Document < (You did the +1 here) (68 now)
3. Document.Save() called
4. Pre-save printing out the current document (68)
5. Post-save printing out the current document (68)

I think what you want to do is implement an instance method on your schema which you can use to define the logic you want. You would call this before you call .save() (Or use it to just call .save() after you have performed your own logic)

example:

```
schema.methods.createRevisionHistory= function(object, callback) {
    // Do comparison logic between this. and object.
    // modify document (this) accordingly
    // this.save(function(err, doc) {
    //    if(err)
    //       return callback(err)
    //    callback(doc);
    // })
};
```

Hope this helps

Read More: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

Comment: So you're saying I should create an **instance** method in the schema which just outputs the document data, then get it in the *pre*, then update the actual doc, then use the same custom method in the *post*, andi t should be different?

Comment: I created a bounty on this. If you can post an example of it working, then you get it :) I just want to be able to see what the document WAS (in the `pre(save)` hook, and compare it with what it IS (in the `post(save)` hook.

Comment: Heh, I'm unable to since im away from my work computer for the next 3 weeks :P. The only way to do what you are asking is if you save the document then in your pre, save it to another variable, then modify the data then in your post save compare.

Answer (score 0):

origDocument have the reference of this.toJSON so when this.toJSON changed in post('save') origDocument also get changed. Try below code:

```
var origDocument 
var testVar = 'Goodbye World'

module.exports = ( schema, options ) => {
    schema.pre( 'save', function( next ) {
        // Store the original value of the documents attrCache.Description value
        origDocument = JSON.parse(JSON.strinigify(this.toJSON().attrCache.Description))

        // Change the testVar value to see if the change is reflected in post(save)
        testVar = 'Hello World'
        next()
    } )

    schema.post( 'save', function(  ) {
        // Attempt to compare the documents previous value of attrCache.Description, with the new value
        console.log("BEFORE:", origDocument)
        console.log("AFTER:", this.toJSON().attrCache.Description)

        // Both of the above values are the same! >.<

        console.log('post(save):',testVar) // result: post(save):Hello World
        // But the above works just fine..
    } )
}
```

Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) I have cleared the reference.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use yet another middleware, and temporarily set the current value to a *non-defined attribute* (so it won't be saved to DB upon `save` call).

E.g.

```
schema.post('init', function(doc) {
  // when document is loaded we store copy of it to separate variable
  // which will be later used for tracking changes
  this._original = doc.toJSON({depopulate: true});
});
```

And then in post save hook do the comparison:

```
schema.post('save', function(doc) {
  // do the diffing of revisions here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In our API, I solved this by using `document.$locals` as the storage location for the original values. `document.$locals` does not get passed to the database and it gets persisted between middleware calls.

#### In `post('find')` and `post('findOne')` hooks:

```
doc.$locals.originalValues = doc.toObject();
```

#### In `pre('save')` and `post('save')` hooks:

```
let changes = doc.getChanges()
,   originalValues = doc.$locals.originalValues;

if (changes.$set) {
    for (let key in changes.$set) {
        _.set(result, key, originalValues[key]);
        result[key] = originalValues[key]; // May be undefined
    }
}
if (changes.$unset) {
    for (let key in changes.$unset) {
        _.set(result, key, originalValues[key]);
        result[key] = originalValues[key]; // Should be defined
    }
}
```

Those are the relevant parts of the code. There's plenty of error checking and edge case detection as well, but fundamentally we're storing the original document whenever we retrieve it, so those values can be compared to the data being saved.

Comment: Any plan to release your API/library/plugin?