# Is there a concept of "protected" fields in findByIdAndUpdate?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Lets say I have a few fields that I don't want modified. In my case my users can utilize a PATCH request which invokes this method:

```
Ad.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new: true})
```

Technically I can "manually" filter the "req.body" object and remove everything that should not be updated even if they specifically send those fields in the request, but is there a better way, perhaps, adding a "protected" flag in the relevant schema something like this:

```
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    protected: true
}
```

Comment: So you want certain fields to not be updateable?

Comment: thats correct..

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436071/does-mongoose-provide-access-to-previous-value-of-property-in-presave) that could solve your problem.

Comment: What does `protected` signifies? How are you setting the initial value?

Comment: To achieve a `protected` type feature for some fields, you can try custom setters for the schema fields.

Comment: You can create a middleware function and that will pass only validated data to next middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Some concerns:

- Wouldn't you validate user's input and throw on errors? Is it still a correct request, if the user sends arbitrary data?
- If you don't validate, how do you sanitize?
- If you don't validate, why don't you filter the request?

I'd strongly recommend doing validation (e.g. with some json-schema-library) and perform sanitization on the values afterwards. On top of that, you can use [Monogram](https://github.com/boosterfuels/monogram) to disallow having some properties being updated. In this case, a request with unexpected params in the payload, would throw and return some error (e.g. BAD REQUEST)